# how to include folders in python code

Tags: python

Let's say two folders. One -X and one more-Y inside X.Now lets say I've set my working path to folder X inside ATOM IDE and now if I want use the folder Y in my code how do I do it?
for example while writing below code I'm inside folder X so

```
import glob2
import datetime
filenames = glob2.glob('*.txt')

#How do  I list files of folder Y only???
with open(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f")+".txt", 'w') as file:
#How do I create file inside folder Y only
    for item in filenames:
        with open(item,"r") as f:
            content = f.read()
            file.write(content)
            file.write("\n")
```

Comment: Could you clarify what folders are, i.e. show us a tree of folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to switching around different directory

```
Path='path to y'
currentDir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(Path)
#do your job here
#now come back to previous directory
os.chdir(currentDir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your directory structure :

```
x/
 some_script.py
 y/
```

Now what you're looking for is to create a file inside y by writing some code in `some_script.py`
This is how you do it :

```
fh =  open('y/a.txt', 'w')
fh.write("Yayy")
fh.close()
```